# What is my voice classification from D2-A4

Tags: analysis

I’m 21, been singing since I was around 16 or 17. I use to struggle up to E4 above middle C. As the years went by , I’ve mastered singing from C4-F#4 around 20. Just recently I’ve found it easier to sing up to G4-A4. My falsetto/headvoice would go up to around A5. I was just wondering what classification of that vocal range would be?

Comment: With due respect, ten seconds of googling found the answer. Even providing an answer will not be very helpful to future readers. So I vtc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answers would be of little value to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You sound like a bass with an extended upper range. Here's a website nicely showing the ranges, especially the diagram down the page. Hope this helps.

https://www.becomesingers.com/vocal-range/vocal-range-chart

Comment: Providing links isn't an accepted thing on this site. Linkrot may deny future readers the pleasure.

Comment: Oh sorry. I saw the "add link" feature and assumed that's what it was for. Is there a "rules of good behavior guide" guide or something like that I can reference for this site?

Comment: That's a little ironic - judging by the comments that are given about links and linkrot. The 'help centre ' is a good start place. Welcome!

Comment: Clearly this is not a friendly place. Thanks for the "ironic" tips.